# Get values from database where column is unique and add condition

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2000

I need help with an advanced SQL-query (MSSQL 2000).

I have a table called Result that lists athletics 100 and 200 meter race-times. A runner can have several racetimes but I want to show only the best time from each runner at each event.

The Result-table contains five columns, Result_id, athlete_id, result_time, result_date, event_code. So athlete_id must be unique when I list the values and result_time must be the fastest (lowest) value. Also I want to be able to choose if event_code should be "= 1" or "= 2", since 100 and 200 meter resulttimes are mixed in the same table.

I asked a similiar question a few days ago, but without the event_code condition.

This is the answer we came up with.

```
select r.*
from result r
inner join (
    select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
    from result
    group by athelete_id
) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
```

Any ideas how I can add the event_code condition to this snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
select r.*
from result r
inner join (
    select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
    from result
    where event_code = 1
    group by athelete_id
) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the event code in the output of the subquery.  Then you can show all events at the same time or choose them in an outer where clause:

```
select r.*
from result r inner join
     (select athlete_id, event_code, min(result_time) as FastestTime
      from result
      group by athlete_id, event_code
     ) rm
     on r.athelete_id = rm.athlete_id and
        r.result_time = rm.FastestTime and
        r.event_code = rm.event_code
-- where event_code = xx
```

The last line is an optional WHERE clause in case you want just one event at a time.

Comment: Thanks! seems to work, but found the other method easier in my case